# How do I access a single term from a post?

Tags: terms

I need help accessing a specific term from a custom taxonomy.

I am getting the terms with

```
 $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'mytax', array("fields" => "all"));
```

If I `print_r($terms)` this is what I get:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => WP_Term Object ( 
        [term_id] => 30 
        [name] => Term1 
        [slug] => term1 
        [term_group] => 0 
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 30 
        [taxonomy] => mytax 
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0 
        [count] => 78 
        [filter] => raw 
    ) 
    [1] => WP_Term Object ( 
        [term_id] => 32 
        [name] => Term2 
        [slug] => term2 
        [term_group] => 0 
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 32 
        [taxonomy] => mytax 
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 30 
        [count] => 44 
        [filter] => raw 
    ) 
)
```

How do I extract the ID for Term1 out of this array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little bit hard to be sure, what are you asking exactly, but... Let me try to answer...

So somewhere in `single.php` you're getting terms for current post using this code:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'mytax', array("fields" => "all"));
```

and you want to get the ID of first term from that list?

If so, you can achieve this with this code:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'mytax', array("fields" => "all"));
$term_id = false;
if ( $terms ) {
    $term_id = $terms[0]->term_id;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just grab a single term, if that's what you want to do.

Using [`get_term_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/):

```
$term = get_term_by( 'name', 'Term1', 'mytax' );
```

should deliver the `WP_Term` object for the term named `Term1` in the taxonomy `mytax`.

[edit] **Get the first term:**

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'mytax', array( "fields" => "all" ) );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
    $term = $terms[0];
    $term_id = $terms[0]->term_id; // If you just need the term ID.
}
```

This will grab the first term from the list you're getting in the original question. Be aware, though, that by default, `wp_get_post_terms()` sorts the terms in ascending order by their `name` field. [You can modify this using `order` and `orderby` in the `$args` parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/):

```
$args = array(
    'fields'  => 'all',
    'orderby' => 'slug',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    // ...for example.
);
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'mytax', $args ) );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
    $term = $terms[0];
    $term_id = $terms[0]->term_id; // If you just need the term ID.
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't really do the trick since this is for a dynamic page template. Is there a way to access the first term without specifying a name to it?